# c syntax problem, to print the sum of multiples of 3 and 5 under a n value

Tags: c, sum, syntax-error

why am i getting a syntax error, i don't think anything is wrong. Thanks..
The syntax error is on line 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    long int sum;
    int an;
    printf("Sum of multiples of three and five\nEnter the nth value\n>> ");
    scanf("%d",&an);
    sum=((3/2*an/3*(an/3+1))+(5/2*an/5*(an/5+1))-(15/2*an/15*(an/15+1)));
    printf("The sum of multiples of 3 and 5 under %d is %ld",an,sum);
}
```

Comment: `sum=(3/2*an/3*(an/3+1))+(5/2*an/5*(an/5+1))-(15/2*an/15*(an/15+1))`..missing `;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting._

Comment: I know i put that there, but still it raises a syntax error

Comment: __Then show us the code you have, not the code you think you have.__

Comment: Well, that's the code that I have, and i think i have.

Comment: Certainly untrue. You edited to add the `;`, now this code does not reproduce the problem you stated earlier.

Comment: Yeah, i actually mistakenly forgot to put that.

Comment: Please, [test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jKg7A594d3y9HVL7) that formula. Are you aware of how integer division (`3/2`, `an/3`, `15/2`...) behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing `;` is an easily fixed typographical error, but it's not the main problem in the posted code.

```
sum = ((3/2*an/3*(an/3+1))+(5/2*an/5*(an/5+1))-(15/2*an/15*(an/15+1)));
//      ^^^   ^     ^       ^^^   ^     ^       ^^^^   ^    ^^^^^
```

This line can't provide the correct answer, due the multiple integer divisions which will "truncate" (the operation is performed on integer types, no floating point variables are actually involved) the intermediate values to integer ones.

You may gain something in code readability by splitting this evaluation in a couple of functions.

```
long int sum_of_multiples(int factor, int n)
{
    // Number of multiples of factor up to n.
    // E.g. 13 / 3 = 4  --> 3, 6, 9, 12 
    long int multiples = n / factor;
    
    // Sum of the multiples using Gauss's method.
    // 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 = 3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 3 * (4 * (4 + 1)) / 2
    // Note that the product of an odd and an even number is always even
    return factor * (multiples * (multiples + 1) / 2);
}

long int sum_of_multiples_of_3_and_5_less_than_n(int n)
{
    if ( n < 1 )
        return 0;
    // The OP wrote "under", so I assume they want to exclude the number itself
    --n;
    return sum_of_multiples(3, n) + sum_of_multiples(5, n) - sum_of_multiples(15, n);
}
```

Comment: Readability is such an undervalued property, specially for newer codes who have not had to return to their code written 6 months prior.

Answer (score 0):

after putting the **;** on line 7, it works fine.